# Run-time error 3021 on Select and Insert query

Tags: mysql, vb6

Can anyone tell me what the problem of my code is?

The compiler says :

> Run-time error '3021' Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record
>   has been deleted.Requested operation requires a current record.

What does this means? Here's my code.

```vb
Public Sub CreateCat(catName As String, CatDescript As String)
Dim sets As String

 qry1 = "select * from tblcategory where category_name='" + catName + "'"
 Set rs = conn.Execute(qry1)

 If rs.Fields("category_name") > 0 Then

    MsgBox "Category name already exist!", vbCritical, "Notification"

 Else

    qry2 = "Insert into tblcategory(category_name,Category_Description)values( '" + LTrim(catName) + "','" + LTrim(CatDescript) + "')"
    conn.Execute(qry2)
    MsgBox "Create Successfully", vbInformation, "Notification"
    CrtUpdtDelCat.Hide
    MainForm.Show

 End If

 Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Pick *one* language/runtime. VB.NET, VBA, VB6 and VBScript are all *different*.

Comment: Which line is causing the error (the `SELECT`, the `INSERT`, or the `rs.Fields("category_name") > 0`)? I'll bet it's the third - think about why you can't access a column value if there is no data returned.